# Reading and re-assigning variable

Tags: variable, iteration

I am trying to create a table by iteratively calculating its values using a temporary variable `accu`:

```
samplingRate = 500;
seconds = 0.2;
bits = 16;
maxV = 2.^bits;
freq = 500;
samples = samplingRate * seconds;
accu = 0;
inc = maxV *freq/samplingRate;
res = Table[
   accu = accu + inc;
   accu = BitAnd[accu, 255];
   accu,
   {t, 0, samples - 1}
   ];
ListPlot[res]
res
```

The line `accu = accu + inc;` is interpreted just the way I intended (it increments `accu` by `inc`. But in the next line, I expect Mathematica to take just the lowest 8 bits of `accu` and re-assign that value to `accu`. Instead, Mathematica seems to interpret this expression an equation that can be solved for `accu`: the first element of the Table is the unevaluated BitAnd function with its two arguments, the next entry is a nested combination of a BitAnd taking the first BitAnd as an argument etc. How can I force Mathematica to simply evaluate BitAnd and assign the result to accu (just like it does in the line above)?

Comment: The problem is in your `seconds = 0.2;` and `maxV = 2.^bits;`; replace them with `seconds = 1/5;` and `maxV = 2^bits;` (or `maxV = BitShiftLeft[1, bits]`). Don't use inexact numbers with functions that expect integers like `BitAnd[]`.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon This answers my question. For the benefit of others who might read this, could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Since `inc` is 65536 and `BaseForm[inc, 2]` is 10000000000000000, `accu` will always be zero.

You can see this by observing the calculations

```
samplingRate = 500;
seconds = 1/5;
bits = 16;
maxV = 2^bits;
freq = 500;

samples = samplingRate seconds
```

> `100`

```
inc = maxV freq/samplingRate
```

> `65536`

```
BaseForm[inc, 2]
```

> [image: binary]

Then, of course,

```
BitAnd[inc, 255]
```

gives zero because the last four bits are all zero, and it follows that

```
accu = 0;
Table[accu = BitAnd[accu + inc, 255], samples] // Short
```

gives

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, <<72>>, 
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`